# Windows media player not showing album art in "Now playing" view mode

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-media-player, album-art

I have edited all the metadata correctly in Mp3tag, added the album art and it's not showing up in the windows media player. The album art is showing up correctly on my phone. Any suggestions?

[image]

[image]
 [image]
But it is showing up in the library view.

Comment: Does this issue only occur with FLAC files, or do you see the same with, for example, MP3 files?

Comment: It happens on both file types.

Comment: In Now Playing mode, please right-click the big music note and select `Visualizations`. Is the `Album art` visualization ticked, as indicated by a black dot?

Comment: Of course it is.

Comment: Then, as already suggested by @Danfossi below, please check if the folder is part of your Music library. If that doesn't help, it could be caused by a WMP setting that was modified. Can you create a new user account and check if you see the same issue there?

Answer (score 0):

is the song/folder part of your multimedia catalog? if it is not, try adding it and reopening windows media player.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
I have another working solution for this:

Open Windows Media Player
Click Organize > Options > Player
Uncheck "Add local media files to library when played"
Delete the Album with wrong Album Art from the library

Open Explorer
Click Organize > Folder and search options > View
Check "Show hidden files, folders, and drives"
Uncheck "Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)"

Go to the folder where music files are stored
Delete AlbumArtSmall.jpg and Folder.jpg

It is advisable to re-check "Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)".